# SQL Query not showing any result

Tags: postgresql

I have a view created name- author_article_log, which looks like this:

---

```
              title              |          name          | status |    date
Candidate is jerk, alleges rival | Rudolf von Treppenwitz | 200 OK | 2016-07-01
```

---

my job is to get the percentage of requests errors in a day,
for which my query is:

```
select i.date, 
       ((count (case when i.status = '404 NOT FOUND'
                    then 1
                    else 0
                end)
        * 1.0
        / count (case when i.date = j.date
                      then 1
                      else 0
                 end)
        ) *100
       ) as percentage
from  author_article_log as i, author_article_log as j
group by i.date, j.date
order by percentage desc;
```

running this query returns no result nor any errors, can anyone please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible to set a `CASE` within a `COUNT` call but I would say that the `SUM` function is more appropriated in your query.

Comment: BTW:  `from  author_article_log as i, author_article_log as j` Do you realize that the two table references are not joined in any way, resulting in a Carthesian product?

Comment: @joop: I've added a join statement to my query which looks like:

from  author_article_log as i join author_article_log as j
on i.date=j.date
      
even then it returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you dont need a self join
- you need `sum()`, not `count()` NOTE: `COUNT(0)` equals `1`
- `DATE` is a keyword; better not use it as a column name

---

```
SELECT zdate,
       100.0 * SUM (CASE WHEN status = '404 NOT FOUND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        / COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM  author_article_log
GROUP BY zdate
ORDER BY percentage DESC
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `WITH` clause to filter your requests

```
WITH errors AS (
  SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS nb_errs
  FROM author_article_log
  WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND'
  GROUP BY date
), total AS (
  SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS nb_queries
  FROM author_article_log
  GROUP BY date
)
SELECT e.date, 100.0 * e.nb_errs / t.nb_queries AS percentage
FROM errors e
JOIN total t ON e.date = t.date
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

Documentation: [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 10: 7.8. WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)